# How to select all table rows (tr) that contained a class (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have a table (#tbLog) and need to select all table rows (tr) that contain a class called private.

Thanks

Answer (score 31):

Simple enough:

`$("#tbLog tr.private").action();`

If you have sub tables (why?), then use this instead to only select the top level `tr`s

`$("#tbLog > tbody > tr.private").action();`

Note that I've included `tbody` in the selector as nearly all browsers will add this tag for you (it's part of the spec).

Answer (score 18):

This how it's done:

```javascript
$('#tbLog tr.private')
```

Answer (score 13):

This way?

```
$("table#tbLog tr.private")
```

Comment: How to make it work if table rows added dynamically with private class?

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#tbLog").children("tr .private")
```

Answer (score 4):

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#tbLog tr.private')
```

That should work...

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

`$('.private')`

Answer (score 1):

I like closest. if private is a class of element inside row

```
$("table#tbLog .private").closest('tr')
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#myTable tr.pagging").click(function () { return false; });`

This is just in case you want to perform no action on tr click.

Answer (score 0):

I think `parent` will work best assuming you want it to contain not be .private you can do

```
$("#tbLog tr .private").parent("tr")
```

this will give you an array of tr's if there is more than one satisfying the condition
hope this helps

Comment: The space is unnecessary between the tr and the class, otherwise it is a working solution